# Store custom field's multiple values in one user meta key

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, user-meta, array

I've added some custom fields into the user profile. It's "Date of Birth".

There are "**month_of_birth**", "**day_of_birth**", "**year_of_birth**".

How to store them in one meta key ('**birth_date**') ?

Here's the code for the custom field :

```
// ADD EXTRA PROFILE FIELD - BIRTH DATE

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3 class="birthdate-info">Date of Birth</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="birth_date">Date of Birth</label></th>
        <td width="30%">
            <select name="month_of_birth" id="month_of_birth">
                <?php
                    $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'month_of_birth', true ) );
                    foreach ( array(
                        'not-selected' => '',
                        'january' => 'January',
                        'february' => 'February',
                        'march' => 'March',
                        'april' => 'April',
                        'may' => 'May',
                        'june' => 'June',
                        'july' => 'July',
                        'august' => 'August',
                        'september' => 'September',
                        'october' => 'October',
                        'november' => 'November',
                        'december' => 'December',
                    ) as $value => $label ) :
                        $selected = selected( $value, $_value, false );
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
            <select name="day_of_birth" id="day_of_birth">
                <?php
                    $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'day_of_birth', true ) );
                    foreach ( array(
                        'not-selected' => '',
                        '1' => '1',
                        '2' => '2',
                        '3' => '3',
                        '4' => '4',
                        '5' => '5',
                        '6' => '6',
                        '7' => '7',
                        '8' => '8',
                        '9' => '9',
                        '10' => '10',
                        '11' => '11',
                        '12' => '12',
                        '13' => '13',
                        '14' => '14',
                        '15' => '15',
                        '16' => '16',
                        '17' => '17',
                        '18' => '18',
                        '19' => '19',
                        '20' => '20',
                        '21' => '21',
                        '22' => '22',
                        '23' => '23',
                        '24' => '24',
                        '25' => '25',
                        '26' => '26',
                        '27' => '27',
                        '28' => '28',
                        '29' => '29',
                        '30' => '30',
                        '31' => '31',
                    ) as $value => $label ) :
                        $selected = selected( $value, $_value, false );
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
            <select name="year_of_birth" id="year_of_birth">
                <?php
                    $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'year_of_birth', true ) );
                    foreach ( array(
                        'not-selected' => '',
                        '1905' => '1905',
                        '1906' => '1906',
                        '1907' => '1907',
                        '1908' => '1908',
                        '1909' => '1909',
                        '1910' => '1910',
                        '1911' => '1911',
                        '1912' => '1912',
                        '1913' => '1913',
                        '1914' => '1914',
                        '1915' => '1915',
                        '1916' => '1916',
                        '1917' => '1917',
                        '1918' => '1918',
                        '1919' => '1919',
                        '1920' => '1920',
                        '1921' => '1921',
                        '1922' => '1922',
                        '1923' => '1923',
                        '1924' => '1924',
                        '1925' => '1925',
                        '1926' => '1926',
                        '1927' => '1927',
                        '1928' => '1928',
                        '1929' => '1929',
                        '1930' => '1930',
                        '1931' => '1931',
                        '1932' => '1932',
                        '1933' => '1933',
                        '1934' => '1934',
                        '1935' => '1935',
                        '1936' => '1936',
                        '1937' => '1937',
                        '1938' => '1938',
                        '1939' => '1939',
                        '1940' => '1940',
                        '1941' => '1941',
                        '1942' => '1942',
                        '1943' => '1943',
                        '1944' => '1944',
                        '1945' => '1945',
                        '1946' => '1946',
                        '1947' => '1947',
                        '1948' => '1948',
                        '1949' => '1949',
                        '1950' => '1950',
                        '1951' => '1951',
                        '1952' => '1952',
                        '1953' => '1953',
                        '1954' => '1954',
                        '1955' => '1955',
                        '1956' => '1956',
                        '1957' => '1957',
                        '1958' => '1958',
                        '1959' => '1959',
                        '1960' => '1960',
                        '1961' => '1961',
                        '1962' => '1962',
                        '1963' => '1963',
                        '1964' => '1964',
                        '1965' => '1965',
                        '1966' => '1966',
                        '1967' => '1967',
                        '1968' => '1968',
                        '1969' => '1969',
                        '1970' => '1970',
                        '1971' => '1971',
                        '1972' => '1972',
                        '1973' => '1973',
                        '1974' => '1974',
                        '1975' => '1975',
                        '1976' => '1976',
                        '1977' => '1977',
                        '1978' => '1978',
                        '1979' => '1979',
                        '1980' => '1980',
                        '1981' => '1981',
                        '1982' => '1982',
                        '1983' => '1983',
                        '1984' => '1984',
                        '1985' => '1985',
                        '1986' => '1986',
                        '1987' => '1987',
                        '1988' => '1988',
                        '1989' => '1989',
                        '1990' => '1990',
                        '1991' => '1991',
                        '1992' => '1992',
                        '1993' => '1993',
                        '1994' => '1994',
                        '1995' => '1995',
                        '1996' => '1996',
                        '1997' => '1997',
                        '1998' => '1998',
                        '1999' => '1999',
                        '2000' => '2000',
                        '2001' => '2001',
                        '2002' => '2002',
                        '2003' => '2003',
                        '2004' => '2004',
                        '2005' => '2005',
                        '2006' => '2006',
                        '2007' => '2007',
                        '2008' => '2008',
                        '2009' => '2009',
                        '2010' => '2010',
                        '2011' => '2011',
                        '2012' => '2012',
                        '2013' => '2013',
                        '2014' => '2014',
                        '2015' => '2015',
                        '2016' => '2016',
                        '2017' => '2017',
                        '2018' => '2018',
                    ) as $value => $label ) :
                        $selected = selected( $value, $_value, false );
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
// SAVE EXTRA PROFILE FIELD - BIRTH DATE

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
update_user_meta( $user_id,'month_of_birth', $_POST['month_of_birth'] );

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
update_user_meta( $user_id,'day_of_birth', $_POST['day_of_birth'] );

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
update_user_meta( $user_id,'year_of_birth', $_POST['year_of_birth'] );
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
SHORTCODE -

```
function user_birthdate_info_shortcode() {
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $birth_date = get_user_meta($user_id, 'birth_date', false);

foreach($birth_date as $key => $value){
echo $value['month'] . '&nbsp;' . $value['day'] . '&nbsp;' . $value['year'];
}
}}
add_shortcode('currentuser_show_birthdate_info', 'user_birthdate_info_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are "**month_of_birth**", "**day_of_birth**",
>   "**year_of_birth**".
>
> How to store them in one meta key ('**birth_date**') ?

If you mean to replace all the three meta keys with one single meta key, then you can save the `birth_date` meta as an `array`, so that the value would be something like this:

```
array(
    'month' => 'august',
    'day'   => '27',
    'year'  => '2018'
)
```

**Here are the steps:**

1. In the `birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields()`, retrieve the
   `birth_date` meta value like this:

   ```
   function birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
       // Get the birth date, which is an array of month, day, and year.
       $birth_date = (array) get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'birth_date', true );
       ?>
   ```
2. Then replace the `name` of the drop-down menus (i.e. `select`
   fields), and replace the code for retrieving the individual birth
   month, day, and year:

   For the birth *month* menu:

   ```
   <select name="month_of_birth" id="month_of_birth"> <!-- before -->
   <select name="birth_date[month]" id="month_of_birth"> <!-- after -->

   $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'month_of_birth', true ) ); // before
   $_value = isset( $birth_date['month'] ) ? $birth_date['month'] : ''; // after
   ```

   For the birth *day* menu:

   ```
   <select name="day_of_birth" id="day_of_birth"> <!-- before -->
   <select name="birth_date[day]" id="day_of_birth"> <!-- after -->

   $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'day_of_birth', true ) ); // before
   $_value = isset( $birth_date['day'] ) ? $birth_date['day'] : ''; // after
   ```

   For the birth *year* menu:

   ```
   <select name="year_of_birth" id="year_of_birth"> <!-- before -->
   <select name="birth_date[year]" id="year_of_birth"> <!-- after -->

   $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'year_of_birth', true ) ); // before
   $_value = isset( $birth_date['year'] ) ? $birth_date['year'] : ''; // after
   ```
3. Then use this for saving the `birth_date` meta value:

   ```
   function birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
       if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
           return false;

       // Make sure we have a valid POSTed data, and if yes, then
       // sanitize/clean each array item.
       $birth_date = isset( $_POST['birth_date'] ) ?
           array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['birth_date'] ) : array();

       update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birth_date', $birth_date );
   }
   ```

### UPDATE

You can retrieve the saved `birth_date` meta value like this:

```
// Note that the last/third parameter is TRUE and not FALSE.
$birth_date = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'birth_date', true );

echo $birth_date['month']; // e.g. august
echo $birth_date['day'];   // e.g. 27
echo $birth_date['year'];  // e.g. 2018
```

If you want the month name to start in uppercase, apply `ucfirst()` on the month name, like this:

```
echo ucfirst( $birth_date['month'] ); // e.g. August
```

So your `user_birthdate_info_shortcode()` could be rewritten into this:

```
function user_birthdate_info_shortcode() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $birth_date = get_user_meta($user_id, 'birth_date', true);

        echo ucfirst( $birth_date['month'] ) . '&nbsp;' . // apply ucfirst()
            $birth_date['day'] . '&nbsp;' . $birth_date['year'];
    }
}
```

---

**Alternatively, just save the month *name* (e.g. `August`) instead of its slug/key (e.g. `august`).** So in the `birthdate_show_extra_profile_fields()` function, change this: (you'd need to re-indent the code)

```
foreach ( array(
    'not-selected' => '',
    'january' => 'January',
    'february' => 'February',
    'march' => 'March',
    'april' => 'April',
    'may' => 'May',
    'june' => 'June',
    'july' => 'July',
    'august' => 'August',
    'september' => 'September',
    'october' => 'October',
    'november' => 'November',
    'december' => 'December',
) as $value => $label ) :
```

to:

```
foreach ( array(
    '',
    'January', 'February', 'March',     'April',   'May',      'June',
    'July',    'August',   'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',
) as $label ) :
    $value = $label; // use the label as the value
```

So your `user_birthdate_info_shortcode()` could be rewritten into this:

```
function user_birthdate_info_shortcode() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $birth_date = get_user_meta($user_id, 'birth_date', true);

        echo $birth_date['month'] . '&nbsp;' . // ucfirst() not necessary
            $birth_date['day'] . '&nbsp;' . $birth_date['year'];
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: I hope you understand the `<!-- before -->` and `<!-- after -->`. But if not, the `<!-- before -->` means your code as it is now, and the `<!-- after -->` is the new code to be used.

Comment: Thank you! You really saved my day. But now I have a problem with the month being all lowercase. I want the first letter to be uppercase. E.g. July instead of july. I've just included **UPDATE 2** for shortcode in my question.

Comment: Please try the *alternate* solution in the **UPDATE** section of the answer. Or if you like, just use the `ucfirst()` method. =)

Comment: Btw, you could also use `echo implode( ' ', $birth_date );` instead of something like `echo $birth_date['month'] . ' ' . $birth_date['day'] . ' ' . $birth_date['year'];`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My code looks clean now. I've marked this as answer. =)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @Alief ;) Do take note though, if you'd like to search by the meta key `birth_date`, it wouldn't be easy since the value is an `array` - or actually, a serialized string.

Answer (score 0):

You can save these fields in the single user meta field like below:

```
 // SAVE EXTRA PROFILE FIELD - BIRTH DATE
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function birthdate_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    // Use this fields to save the selected the options
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'month_of_birth', $_POST['month_of_birth'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'day_of_birth', $_POST['day_of_birth'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'year_of_birth', $_POST['year_of_birth'] );


    $date_of_birth = array();
    $date_of_birth[] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['year_of_birth'] );
    $date_of_birth[] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['month_of_birth'] );
    $date_of_birth[] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['day_of_birth'] );

    // Use this fields to show and perform any operations
    // Delete the birth_date if all fields are empty.
    if( empty( $date_of_birth ) && count($date_of_birth) == 0 )
        delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'birth_date' );
    else
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birth_date', join('/', $date_of_birth ) ); 
}
```

Note: Comments in the code are importants.

Regards,
Baikare Sandeep.

Comment: Thank you. But after adding this code, there are four meta keys now in my database (birth_date, month_of_birth, day_of_birth, year_of_birth). When I delete those three meta keys, the fields get empty again. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, in that case, you can remove the combined field as well after removing these all fields. I have updated code. Please check it.